# Keep changed class variables

Tags: c++, class

I want to know if there is any way to keep changed variables inside of the class. Example:

```
class Numbers{
  int x;

  Numbers();

public:
  void set(int y);
  void print();
};

void Numbers::set(int y){
  x=y;
}

void Numbers::print(){
  cout<<x<<endl;
}


int main(){
  Numbers x;
  x.set(3);
  x.print();

  Numbers x2;
  x2.print(); // here I want to display "3", not 0 as default

  return 0;
}
```

However I do **not** want to use global variables outside of the class as the temp variables.

Comment: look at `static` varibales, they are shared across all instances of a class.

Comment: How to define static varibles in int main? I know I can write like: int Numbers::x=10; but how to do that in int main?

Answer (score 4):

You have to define the variable `static`

```
class Numbers{
    static int x;

public:
     static void set( int i ){ x = i; }
     void print(){ std::cout << x << std::endl; } // maybe this should be static
};

int Numbers::x = 0;


int main()
{
    Numbers x1, x2;
    x1.print();  // prints 0

    x1.set( 1 );
    // above is same as
    Numbers::set( 1 );

    x1.print();  // prints 1

    x2.print();  // prints 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all your code will not be compiled because you declared the default constructor of the class as private and did not define it .

As for your question then you could use a static data member. For example

```
#include <iostream>

class Numbers
{
private:
  static int x;
public:
  Numbers() {}

  void set( int y ) { x = y; }
  void print() const { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
};

int Numbers::x;

int main()
{
   Numbers x;
   x.set( 3 );
   x.print();

   Numbers x2;
   x2.print();
}
```

Also these member functions could be defined as static member functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare like this

```
static int myVariable = 0;
```

Here is some information of static variables

> The use of static inside a function is the simplest. It simply means
>   that once the variable has been initialized, it remains in memory
>   until the end of the program. You can think of it as saying that the
>   variable sticks around, maintaining its value, until the program
>   completely ends. For instance, you can use a static variable to record
>   the number of times a function has been called simply by including the
>   lines static int count =0; and count++; inside the function. Because
>   count is a static variable, the line "static int count = 0;" will only
>   be executed once. Whenever the function is called, count will have the
>   last value assigned to it.

You can keep reading more here :

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html